# MarkerManager Google Map Utility V2: intercept markerDrag events

Tags: android, dictionary

I am facing a problem with MarkerManager: 
after adding elements to the cluster manager, I do not know how to proceed to intercept events related to dragging a marker. The documentation is very poor about this topic. Thanks to anyone who will help me.

Comment: How about you show us what u your tried so far. Post your code and describe to us the specific problems you encountered.